# 500 error message when i try and redirect to signup and login page in production

Tags: python, django

I get an error page when I try and access my signup or login pages in production, my login and signup pages work well in development so not sure it has anything to do with urls.py unless I'm missing something.

Here is how my project is structured:

```
home
-->etc
-->thegradientboostmvp
---->classroom
       >urls.py
       >models.py
---->django-app
       >urls.py
       >settings.py
       >wsgi.py
---->public
       >static
          >admin
          >css
          >img
          >vendor
          >second
          >third
          >fourth
---->static
------>admin
------>css
------>img
------>second
           >css
           >js
           >img
------>third
           >css
           >js
           >img
------>fourth
           >img
           >js
           >css
---->templates
```

This is what I have in django-app/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import include, path
from classroom.views import classroom, students, teachers
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('classroom.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('accounts/signup/', classroom.SignUpView.as_view(), name='signup'),
    path('accounts/signup/student/', students.StudentSignUpView.as_view(), name='student_signup'),
    path('accounts/signup/teacher/', teachers.TeacherSignUpView.as_view(), name='teacher_signup'),
]
```

and classroom/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', classroom.home, name='home'),
    path('about', classroom.about, name='about'),
    path('courses', classroom.courses, name='courses'),
    path('course_details', classroom.course_details, name='course_details'),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('accounts/signup/', classroom.SignUpView.as_view(), name='signup'),
    path('accounts/signup/student/', students.StudentSignUpView.as_view(), name='student_signup'),
    path('accounts/signup/teacher/', teachers.TeacherSignUpView.as_view(), name='teacher_signup'),

    path('students/', include(([
        path('', students.dashboard, name='quiz_list'),
        path('logout', students.logout_request, name="logout"),
        path('dashboard', students.dashboard, name='app-student-dashboard'),
        path('directory_grid', students.directory_grid, name='app-directory-grid'),
        path('take_course', students.take_course, name='app-take-course'),
        path('edit_user', students.edit_user, name='edit_user'),
        path('mentors', students.mentor_list, name='mentors'),
    ], 'classroom'), namespace='students')),

    path('teachers/', include(([
        path('', teachers.QuizListView.as_view(), name='app-instructor-dashboard'),
        path('logout', teachers.logout_request, name="logout"),
        path('edit_user', teachers.edit_user, name='edit_user'),
        path('mentor_messages', teachers.mentor_messages, name='mentor_messages'),
        path('statement', teachers.statement, name='app-instructor-statement'),
        path('course_details', teachers.course_details, name='app-take-course'),
        path('students', teachers.student_list, name='students'),
        path('take_course', teachers.take_course, name='app-take-course'),
        path('payment_view', teachers.payment_view, name='payment_view'),

    ], 'classroom'), namespace='teachers')),

#admin dashboard
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

I redirect to the login page using

```
"{% url 'signup' %}"
```

However I get an error 500 message

Comment: And what exception is generated?

Comment: Please post the error message and traceback (from your production's log). Also, the fact that it only breaks on your production server might be an indication that there's some discrepency between your production env and dev env, so you really want to investigate this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to:

```
"{% url 'django-app:signup' %}"
```

And if You use Django 2+ You should to add `app_name = 'django-app'` to your `django-app.urls`

django_app/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import include, path
from classroom.views import classroom, students, teachers
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

app_name = 'django-app'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('classroom.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('accounts/signup/', classroom.SignUpView.as_view(), name='signup'),
    path('accounts/signup/student/', students.StudentSignUpView.as_view(), name='student_signup'),
    path('accounts/signup/teacher/', teachers.TeacherSignUpView.as_view(), name='teacher_signup'),
]
```

Comment: Thanks, do you mind adding a breakdown of how my urls.py will look with that addition

Comment: Yep, no problem. And You should to add the same to all apps.